# Data source element is of data type x, the mapped item is of data type y (Sharepoint designer)

Tags: external-content-type

I have built an external content type based on a database table. Originally, a certain column was of type int, but recently it has been changed to decimal. Now I get an error in the ReadList and ReadItem operation of the content type.

> Data source element xyz is of data type decimal, the mapped item is of data type Int32. These data types cannot be converted automatically at runtime.

Is there a way to repair the content type? Especially, what is meant by "mapped item"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I found so far is to remove the column from the table, then update sharepoint and add the column again. By this method you can avoid deleting the complete content type.